# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 with Vaadin and jInstagram

Tags: java, vaadin, instagram, vaadin7

I am currently using the Vaadin 7 framework and the jInstagram (A Java wrapper for the Instagram API) library to create a web application. The server I am using is run jetty.

Using Eclipse Kepler on OSX 10.9

The problem is that I keep getting this error:

"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/test/testUI$Servlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

I have already installed JRE 7 and changed the project settings to use JRE 7.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

The problem is that the JVM that is actually running the Jetty server and your webapp code is not Java 7.  Unfortunately, you haven't told us enough for us to know why that is, but it is something to do with the way that the Jetty server is being launched.

Comment: Hi will it help if I copy and paste my code here? The server I am using is the "Run Jetty" plugin from the Eclipse marketplace.

Comment: The problem is not in your code, so copy-pasting it won't help.  If you are launching Jetty from Eclipse, then the problem is most likely in the launch configuration.  (I'm not familiar with that plugin ...)

Comment: Changed the launch configuration and that solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

You will get this error when you try to run a Java code with version lesser than the version used to compile the code. Code should work even if the code is compiled in Java 6 and run in Java 7. So the only reason I can see you getting that error is though you have set project settings to use Java 7 it is somehow still using a lesser version. You can check your module specific setting as that override project level settings. Also check you java environment variables used because if you are running server from command line those will be the one which are picked. You can try `java -version`. Also see if `JAVA_HOME` variable is set to Java 7 JDK dir.

Comment: I just used this line of code in the terminal to set the JAVA_HOME variable. Is this the way to do it?
"export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"

Comment: You can read it here ( http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-set-javahome-environment-in.html )

Answer (score 0):

The Java versions are as follows.

```
  J2SE 8 = 52,
    J2SE 7 = 51,
    J2SE 6.0 = 50,
    J2SE 5.0 = 49,
    JDK 1.4 = 48,
    JDK 1.3 = 47,
    JDK 1.2 = 46,
    JDK 1.1 = 45
```

As per package description it seems that it is your class(you have written the src). The exception reported by you generally thrown when you compiled source file with higher/lower version of jdk then the version you are using in runtime.

To fix this problem you have to use same version in compiling(JDK) and running (JVM). To check the version of compiler and JVM use following commands.

```
Compiler 
javac -version


JVM 
javac -version
```

Comment: Is this output correct?

java -version: 

java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

javac -version: 

javac 1.7.0_60